# Bluemix > IBM API Connect > IBM Developer Toolkit: ECONNREFUSED Errors

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop, apiconnect

Learning how to deploy the demo project to IBM API Connect on Bluemix ([get-started](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_003.html#apic_009)) and get the following errors after run apic edit to start IBM Developer Toolkit local site:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrHmz.png)

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The ECONNREFUSED error means that your app is unable to connect to the mentioned port. It may happen because of you didn't configure your the port or another app on that port is not running.

Comment: I have the same issue on Linux Mint 17.3 with port 33780...I have checked but nothing on it so I have tried reinstalling...anyway no success..

Answer (score 1):

Just tried the same and I am not able to reproduce the issue, since the "apic edit" step works fine for me. I guess this is an issue related to your machine. The error is quite clear and it means that Express.js is not able to connect to that port. The first step is to check that port to see if it's blocked by the host system. However I see different ports in the error message, so the problem could be different (check your firewall settings). Moreover, I would try to install *apic* again running `sudo npm install -g apiconnect` and double check that the prerequisites are already installed. It could be throwing an error that you didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and will let you know what happens.  I was able to reproduce this issue on my home computer over the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try publish in the interface `0.0.0.0`:

```
export HOST=0.0.0.0
apic edit
```